# Visual Studio SSIS: CSPL on whether column is in list of values

Tags: ssis

I am trying to do a conditional split, but I seem to be missing an `IN` operator. Say you have a column month (`int`) and want to split based on whether month is in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) or else. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by making a conditional split on whether month is greater or equal to 1 and smaller or equal to 12.

Comment: yes but I would like to catch cases of data entry error (say month = 2.5)